# Geo Tools Conformal and Distortion Transform

Tags: java, geotools

I'm using WFS service to get geometry values of some Australian land parcels based on the local grid it belongs to. I receive the coordinates in WSG84 and I'm converting it to relevant coordinate system (i.e GDA2020/PCG2020) with below code.

```
JTS.transform(geometry, CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS));
```

However above has some issue with the accuracy in transformed coordinates. And I'm trying to convert the coordinates with Conformal and Distortion in here - https://www.icsm.gov.au/datum/gda-transformation-products-and-tools/transformation-grids

I have tried some workaround to resolve this issue by placing https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids/blob/master/GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb file inside `src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/gridshift` of my maven multi module project, however that does not count while transforming the coordinates.

After that I have tried below code and it seems the output coordinates are not right.

```
JTS.transform(geometry, new NTv2Transform(new URI("GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb")));
```

Can anyone help me to work it out properly ? Is there way to tell NTv2Transform to use source and target coordinate systems while transforming ? I'm new to this domain and I'm trying to figure out the correct way to do this.

Comment: can you please provide a simple example code that demonstrates your issue and includes the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from the [ICSM](https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids) page (and I'm not a projections expert and especially not when Australia is concerned) the conformal and distortion transform is used when going from GDA94 to GDA2020, so I produced the following test code (note that currently it will only work with the 26-SNAPSHOT jars for reasons that will become clear.

```
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;

public class GDA94_Conf_DIst {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FactoryException {
    CoordinateReferenceSystem gda94 = CRS.decode("epsg:4283");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem gda2020 = CRS.decode("epsg:7844");

    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(gda94, gda2020, "EPSG:8447");
    System.out.println(transform);

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    transform = CRS.findMathTransform(gda94, gda2020);
    System.out.println(transform);
  }

}
```

With out the grid file present in `/src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/gridshift` I get the following output (both results are the same):

```
    CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
        PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
        PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
      PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
        PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
        PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
        PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356]], 
      PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame Rotation (geog2D domain)", 
        PARAMETER["dx", 0.06155], 
        PARAMETER["dy", -0.01087], 
        PARAMETER["dz", -0.04019], 
        PARAMETER["ex", -0.03949239999999996], 
        PARAMETER["ey", -0.03272209999999997], 
        PARAMETER["ez", -0.032897899999999966], 
        PARAMETER["ppm", -0.009993999960933309]], 
      PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
        PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
        PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
        PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356]], 
      PARAM_MT["Affine", 
        PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
        PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
        PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
        PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
      PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
        PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
        PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
        PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356]], 
      PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame Rotation (geog2D domain)", 
        PARAMETER["dx", 0.06155], 
        PARAMETER["dy", -0.01087], 
        PARAMETER["dz", -0.04019], 
        PARAMETER["ex", -0.03949239999999996], 
        PARAMETER["ey", -0.03272209999999997], 
        PARAMETER["ez", -0.032897899999999966], 
        PARAMETER["ppm", -0.009993999960933309]], 
      PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
        PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
        PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
        PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356]], 
      PARAM_MT["Affine", 
        PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
        PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
        PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

When I add `GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb` to the `gridshift` folder **and** recompile the project (after I applied this [patch](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/3568)). I get this:

```
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["NTv2", 
    PARAMETER["Latitude and longitude difference file", "GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb"]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356]], 
  PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame Rotation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", 0.06155], 
    PARAMETER["dy", -0.01087], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -0.04019], 
    PARAMETER["ex", -0.03949239999999996], 
    PARAMETER["ey", -0.03272209999999997], 
    PARAMETER["ez", -0.032897899999999966], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", -0.009993999960933309]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

The default `findMathTransform` doesn't choose the grid file as less accurate (?) at 0.05 while the default is 0.01 (according to the EPSG database), which is why I added the [ability to pick a specific transform](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6920) in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and the patches you have added. Still I'm trying to clear out one thing. If I want to convert geometry from WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) to GDA2020/PCG2020 (EPSG:8031), should I transform it with multiple steps ? i.e WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) to GDA94 (EPSG:4283), and then GDA94 (EPSG:4283) to GDA2020 (EPSG:7844) using EPSG:8447 transformation in gsb file, and then finally GDA2020 (EPSG:7844) to GDA2020/PCG2020 (EPSG:8031).

Comment: I think that you need to ask a expert on Australian crs for the best answer to that. We'd be happy to post some thing on the GeoTools blog if you find out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the multiple step approach increase the accuracy of final coordinates after transformation and it's pretty much better than before :)